# YACC/Bison grammar rules overlap, parsing one rule as two separate rules

Tags: bison, yacc

I have been working on a compiler for the Lua programming language and decided to use Bison for AST generation. A very annoying bug has come up where my grammatical definition for function calls is parsed as an identifier and then an expression group (`( ... )`). Here is the relevant code:

```
variable 
    : IDENTIFIER_T
    | prefix_expression LEFT_SQUARE_T expression RIGHT_SQUARE_T
        { $$ = node_expression_index(@$, $1, $3); }
    | prefix_expression DOT_T IDENTIFIER_T
        { $$ = node_name_index(@$, $1, $3, false); }
;

prefix_expression  
    : call 
    | LEFT_PARAN_T expression RIGHT_PARAN_T
        { $$ = node_expression_group(@$, $2); }
    | variable_name_reference
;

arguments
    : LEFT_PARAN_T RIGHT_PARAN_T
        { $$ = NULL; }
    | LEFT_PARAN_T expression_list RIGHT_PARAN_T
        { $$ = $2; }
    | STRING_T
;

call 
    : prefix_expression arguments
        { $$ = node_call(@$, $1, $2, false); }
    | prefix_expression COLON_T IDENTIFIER_T arguments
        { $$ = node_call(@$, node_name_index(@$, $1, $3, true), $4, true); }
;

expression
  : NIL_T  | FALSE_T | TRUE_T | NUMBER_T | STRING_T | VARARG_T  
  | binary_operation | prefix_expression | unary_operation | array_constructor
  | table_constructor 
  | FUNCTION_T function_body
    { $$ = $2; }
;
```

And the defintion for `variable_name_reference` is here:

```
variable_name_reference
    : variable
        { $$ = node_name_reference(@$, $1); }
;
```

In other words, `print(f())` would give a syntax error because bison parses `f()` as `f ()` (the space indicating seperation in rules).

I have tried moving the call definition above the variable_name_reference definition in hopes that the parser attempts to find a function call first.

Comment: There are no conflicts in the grammar fragment you've shown, and it has no problem parsing something like `print(f())`, so whatever your problem is, it is not here and not what you think it is.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Really? Whenever I pass ``print(f())`` to the parser it responds with 'syntax error' at the location of the ``()``. I don't see how this could be anything else?

Comment: Not with just the grammar fragment you've posted here you don't.  You might get that with a larger grammar that adds more rules, but that would be due to a conflict introduced by those rules you're not showing here.  If bison accepts the grammar with no conflicts (including conflicts resolved by precedence rules, which can be hard to see), then there are no ambiguities in the grammar, so that can't happen.

Comment: @ChrisDodd You were right! After running bison in debug mode I was able to identify an external rule that was messing with my function calls. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue! I had another use of `variable_name_reference` in a different grammar definition which was confusing Bison. My grammar definitions provided were valid.